# Steps of Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

On page 15 of "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Niven,Zuckerman and Montgomery, the numbers of steps requires is given as 3logc ,where it is the natural log.
Can anyone please help me understand this?
The proofs I've seen assert that it is log2 ab, then how is this possible?

Comment: First, \$\log$ probably denotes the binary log. And perhaps it is actually the complexity of the *extended* Euclidean algorithm, which also computes the coefficients of a *Bézout*'s relation.

Comment: They are probably talking about an upper bound, not the best possible. For that, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Worst-case.

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned that it is to the base e. That is why I am confused